# Eclipse JDT: Java Search Engine

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I need to find all the Java types (classe, interface, enum, annotation) in all projectes' source directories of workspace, given a name as String. For example, input "Test" would return all the Java types whose names start with "Test" defined in all the projects source directories. I tried to handle this with JDT's SearchEngine as follows

```
SearchPattern pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern("Test",
            IJavaSearchConstants.TYPE, IJavaSearchConstants.DECLARATIONS,
            SearchPattern.R_PREFIX_MATCH);
IJavaSearchScope scope = SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope();
SearchRequestor requestor = new SearchRequestor() {
        public void acceptSearchMatch(SearchMatch match) {
            System.out.println("Found: " + match.getElement());
        }
};
SearchEngine searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
try {
        searchEngine.search(pattern, new SearchParticipant[] { SearchEngine
                        .getDefaultSearchParticipant() }, scope, requestor,
                        null);
} catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code above returned some java types not in Eclipse workspace. For example:

Found: TestSimple (not open) [in TestSimple.class [in <default> [in /home/me/test]]]

TestSimple.java is a file created from command line in my home directory and it has nothing to do with Eclipse projects. (My Eclipse workspace is defined in /home/me/eclipse/workspace.) I am not sure why it is included in the search result? Is SearchEngine the best way to handle this scenario, given the fact that I just need the java type names, I don't need anything inside a class such as field, method or reference? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I just double checked path /home/me/test is on the build path of one test project in Eclipse. So that is not a problem. Any suggestion on the second question is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using the much simpler [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) instead of `SearchEngine` the detailed functionality of which you don't need anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to build a more confined search scope, then, asking each IJavaProject for all of its package fragment roots (`IJavaProject#getAllPackageFragmentRoots()`) and including only those returning `K_SOURCE` from `IPackageFragmentRoot#getKind()` to avoid getting types from referenced libraries as well. A search on just names shouldn't do much more than hit the indexes that are already being stored. You can't just rely on filenames because it would miss inner classes entirely.